# How to measure rainfall? And how is it determined for a specific location?

Tags: earth, measurements, weather

How is rainfall measure in a pinpoint location?

This is what I think:
There are automatic rainfall measuring stations at: A, B, C.

But say I want to know point D, located between A and B, its rainfall level.

How do I figure that out?  Do I take the average?  Do I go to the nearest neighbor on the map?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To measure at a particular location you set up a [rain gauge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_gauge) there.  There are various technologies.  Nearby stations will give you an idea of the rain at the point you want, but neither averaging nor taking the closest will be sure.  There can be local effects that increase the rain at a given point.  Often the bulk of the rain will come from spotty storm cells.  If more happen to pass over A and B than D, the measurements will not be accurate for D.

Comment: You have a very good point about spotty storm cells.  If A and B gets much rain, would it be a good guess to conclude D gets much rain.

Comment: It varies a lot.  In general, a heavy storm will be heavy over a wide region.  In some places rain is quite localized-you should see what happens where you are interested.  Even once you get a rain gauge there are issues-trees, overhanging roofs, etc.  I have no clear spot in my yard to set one up.  You also have to worry about the effects of rain not falling vertically-it often doesn't.

Comment: Interesting!  I have data already measured from gps, every 50 miles apart up-down and left-right, a device reports me the measuring.

Comment: 50 miles is an enormous distance.  Near San Jose, CA, we have places within 20 miles that average 10 and 80 inches per year. Think Kauai, HI, which has Mount Waialeale, the "wettest place on earth" averaging 462 inches per year, while Poipu averages 30-40 inches per year.  To my eye they are about 15 miles apart.

Answer (score -1):

You go to point D and measure it, otherwise it's only a "best guess".

Comment: A "best guess" can be very good. Every measurement, in the end, reduces uncertainty in a quantity - a "good" measurement will reduce the uncertainty more than a "bad" measurement. I find this a very uninformative answer.

Comment: OK, did you down vote the other answer too?  (It seems like we said the same thing.)